# What is the Sass equivalent to this LESS code that applies multiple sub-CSS classes?

Tags: css, sass

This works in LESS:

```
.block {

  &--modifer1 {
    background: red;
  }

  &--modifier2 {
    background: blue;
  }

  // If block has both modifiers
  &--modifer&--modifier2 {
    background: orange;
  }

}
```

And the last selector becomes (as expected);

```
.block--modifer.block--modifier2 {
  background: orange;
}
```

Can be tried here:

http://winless.org/online-less-compiler

But the same code does not work for Sass, which can be tried here:

http://www.sassmeister.com/

Instead you get the error:

```
Invalid CSS after "&--modifer": expected "{", was "&--modifier2"
"&--modifier2" may only be used at the beginning of a compound selector.
```

How do you write this simple example with Sass?

Comment: where is your sass code?

Comment: That's my question =)

Comment: I think you need a mixin

Comment: You can always use a double-nested selector, with one for `&.block--modifier2` in the block for `&--modifer`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily write it by interpolating the parent selector `&`.

```
.block {

  &--modifer1 {
    background: red;
  }

  &--modifier2 {
    background: blue;
  }

  // Just interpolate parent selector
  &--modifer#{&}--modifier2 {
    background: orange;
  }

}
```

Which generates the following css

```
.block--modifer1 {
  background: red; }

.block--modifier2 {
  background: blue; }

.block--modifer.block--modifier2 {
  background: orange; }
```

Comment: _No problemo_! Happy to help :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this

Demo - http://www.sassmeister.com/gist/d75b6e741a1ec0d58a544abfc72c6ab7

```
.block{

  &--modifer1 {
    background: red;
  }

  &--modifier2 {
    background: blue;
  }

 &--modifier {
    @at-root &#{&}2 {
        color:orange;
    }
}

}
```

Output

```
.block--modifer1 {
  background: red;
}
.block--modifier2 {
  background: blue;
}
.block--modifier.block--modifier2 {
  color: orange;
}
```